# Sub function Excel VBA

Tags: excel, function, vba

Why would this be a syntax error? it is asking for an = sign

cyberlinkcompute("A1","B2")

---

private sub cyberlinkcompute ( a as string, b as string)

end sub

isnt a sub function something that does not need an =?
thanks in advance

Comment: Uae `cyberlinkcompute "A1","B2"`instead. Here's an [interesting post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses or put the word Call in front of the procedure name

Answer (score 1):

Its the function-like parentheses it dislikes so either;

```
cyberlinkcompute "A1","B2"
```

or less advisably:

```
call cyberlinkcompute("A1","B2")
```

Comment: for my own interest, why is call less advisable?

Comment: I use the `Call` syntax when creating libraries because it is much easier to migrate the library code to VB or VB.NET. To migrate to VB, the syntax does not change. To migrate to VB, just remove the `Call` keyword.